# Supervisor isn't supervised

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

The tag info for [supervisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/supervisor) says:

> Supervisors are one of the core things that make Erlang/OTP what it is. An active OTP application consists of one or more processes that do the work. Those processes are started indirectly by supervisors, which are responsible for supervising them and restarting them if necessary. A running application is essentially a tree of processes, both supervisors and workers, where the root of the tree is the root supervisor.

When looking at the questions tagged with it most seem to be talking about Python, celery, supervisord, django etc. There are 117 questions tagged also with [erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erlang) which actually belong to this tag.

It seems this tag is quite unclear and people use it for general supervisor questions. Should it be renamed to [supervisor-erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/supervisor-erlang) instead for clarity? There is already a tag for [supervisord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/supervisord) that should be used for the questions about supervisord so the ones erroneously using this tag could be edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've cleaned up the tag and renamed it to [erlang-supervisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erlang-supervisor). There are now ~160 posts using that tag.

Cleaning up consisted of

- Retagging posts about the `supervisord` project to [supervisord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/supervisord).
- Removing the tag from [apache-storm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-storm) projects (open to suggestions for a new tag there)
- Retagged some posts about kernel programming to [supervisor-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/supervisor-mode)
- Retagged posts about the Node.js `supervisor` project to [node-supervisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-supervisor)
- Retagged posts about the Akka supervisor strategy to [akka-supervision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka-supervision) (I cleaned out the [supervisorstrategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/supervisorstrategy) tag in the process)

and closing a bunch of off-topic posts (mostly *general computing*).

Just to be explicit: the [supervisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/supervisor) tag is gone entirely.